# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First Override Conventions Confusion

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Code-First conventions are really throwing me for a loop. I am working with an existing database, so I am mixing new tables with existing tables. I'm using the EntityConfiguration class when I need to configure different mapping/relations, so lets say I have a Customer and an order. If conventions are not in-line, do I need to create two EntityConfiguration classes, one for each end? Is it yes..no..sometimes? I'm really confused here...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your mappings look like its hard to say, but I would try something like this for a custom one-to-many mapping.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasRequired(o => o.Customer)
        .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
        .HasForeignKey(o => o.CustomerId); 

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
}
```

Comment: ok, so here you are starting with the order and then configuring. could you also start with the custom and essentially do the same thing? this is where my confusion is.